# Get the docstring of the test methods from a result of unit testing

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I want to test uploaded python programs with the `unittest` module on a django based web site and give a useful feedback to the student. I created some helper function to get statistics (how many failures and errors) and messages.

```
def suite(*test_cases):
    suites = [unittest.makeSuite(case) for case in test_cases]
    return unittest.TestSuite(suites)


def testcase_statistics_and_messages(*test_cases):
    devnull = open('/dev/null', "w")
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=devnull)
    test_suite = suite(*test_cases)
    test_result = runner.run(test_suite)
    devnull.close()

    failure_messages = [mesg for test_case, mesg in test_result.failures]
    number_of_failures = len(failure_messages)
    error_messages = [mesg for test_case, mesg in test_result.errors]
    number_of_errors = len(error_messages)
    number_of_test_cases = test_suite.countTestCases()
    number_of_successes = (number_of_test_cases
                           - number_of_errors - number_of_failures)

    return dict(
        number_of_test_cases=number_of_test_cases,
        failure_messages=failure_messages,
        error_messages=error_messages,
        number_of_successes=number_of_successes,
        number_of_errors=number_of_errors,
        number_of_failures=number_of_failures,
    )
```

I save the program of the student and the unit tests into a file. I import the file, and I get the list of the TestCase classes from the file, and run the functions above. (I can handle SyntaxError, IndentationError and runtime errors of the program uploaded by the student.)

However the messages I got from the unit tests are not too useful for the students. E.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpnda6x_60.py", line 39, in test_discriminant_returns_the_proper_values
    self.assertEqual(discriminant(*args), return_values)
AssertionError: -2 != 0
```

If I would get for example the docstring of the test method of the `TestCase`, I would be happy. I can not find a straightforward way to do this. If I would get the name of the TestCase and the method, I could get the docstring with the `eval` function. Is there an easier way, than to get the test method names from the messages and go through the TestCases and check whether there is a test method called like I have found in the message.

I have tried to use `msg` keyword arguments to the asserts, but than it is a pain to write unit tests, and I need to use e.g. regular expression to get the informative part of the message.

I have Python 3.2 on the server I want to run this django project on.

Comment: Good question. Looking at the unittest source I don't think there's  way to programmatically get the values, other than parsing the traceback / error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `TestCase` like:

```
class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        """If this fails, it may not be your fault.
        Try hacking the integer cache. Evil laugh."""
        self.assertEqual(3, 4)
```

You can later, in your `testcase_statistics_and_messages` function, get first line of your doc string using `test_case.shortDescription()`, or the full doc string using `test_case._testMethodDoc`. So, adding those to your function (and to the return dict):

```
short_docs = [test_case.shortDescription() for test_case, mesg in test_result.failures]
docs = [test_case._testMethodDoc for test_case, mesg in test_result.failures]
```

And then printing the results using:

```
for key, value in testcase_statistics_and_messages(ExampleTestCase).items():
    print(key, "==>", value)
```

Gives me:

```
short_docs ==> ['If this fails, it may not be your fault.']
number_of_test_cases ==> 1
error_messages ==> []
docs ==> ['If this fails, it may not be your fault.\n        Try hacking the integer cache. Evil laugh.']
failure_messages ==> ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "ut.py", line 9, in test_example\n    self.assertEqual(3, 4)\nAssertionError: 3 != 4\n']
number_of_failures ==> 1
number_of_errors ==> 0
number_of_successes ==> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution - override the specific assertion methods that you're using (`assertEqual`, etc, hopefully not too many) and store the variables in a JSON string as message:

```
import json
import unittest

class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    longMessage = False

    def assertEqual(self, first, second, msg=None):
        super(ExampleTestCase, self).assertEqual(first, second, msg=json.dumps({
            'first': first,
            'second': second,
        }))

    def test_example(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 4)
```

By using `longMessage = False` Python will return the assertion message to you without modifying it further.

The above will give you:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 797, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 790, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: {"first": 3, "second": 4}
```

The last line of this is much easier to parse using `json.loads`. It's up to you to make the sure the values can be serialised and deserialised to/from JSON.

Lastly, you may also need to customize running the tests to easily parse each of the tracebacks.

This all being said, if you can avoid it, it may be better to review whether your use case can be done using one of the other Python testing frameworks (nosetests, py.tests, etc). After reviewing the situation it may turn out that writing your own testing framework is the best approach to get the best error messages. For example:

```
x = 3
y = 4
try:
    assert x == y
except AssertionError:
    return ...  # your error message here (can be a string or an arbitrary object)
```